# Ubuntu 22.04 can't mount encrypted LVM

Tags: boot, 22.04, lvm, luks

after upgrading to the latest kernel version of 22.04 my laptop gets stuck during boot.
I'm prompted to insert my LUKS password, but then it fails to mount the encrypted file system. The encrypted partition contains a LVM system with two partitions (root and swap file system).

The first 22.04 kernel did work and I could start my system by selecting an older kernel, but after the last update this older kernel version is gone and my system is non functional.

### Details

My encrypted partition is `/dev/nvme0n1p3`.

After running `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt` I get the `/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt` device correctly.
When I try to mount it directly, it fails (`invalid agument`). Which is probably because its a LVM volume.

When I boot from a rescue system, I can get the volumes mounted correctly by calling `lvmdiskscan`, `vgscan`, and `lvscan`.
That shows me that the data is still there.

I tried to change the encryption keys to LUKS2 but it didn't help. I'm out of ideas how to solve this problem. Any help appreciated.

Best regards,
Thomas

### Additional Thoughts:

Is it a hardware problem?

- Probably not, it worked with one specific kernel and not with another. Also I could mount the file systems manually from a rescue system

Is it a BIOS problem?

- Probably not, see comment above on hardware problem

### Update:

In the end I re-installed my system to get it running again since none of the solutions I tried did work. Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

- 1st reset BIOS configurations
- 2nd check UEFI vs. BIOS
- 3rd enable/disable secure boot
- 4th set admin password in BIOS [BUT BE AWARE DONT LOSE THAT PASSWORD].
- 5th It could be many things: your installation was broken, your HDD/SSD is malfunctioning, you set the wrong password [some keyboards may send the wrong keycode], your hardware isn't compatible with that type of installation or you made some mistake.

Comment: I had the same ideas, already checked all bios settings, but they were ok and changes in SATA would make my system un-bootable (tried it).
Anyway the last weeks it worked reproducibly with one specific kernel image version and not with another (yes, I know this is strange)

Comment: The options I provided must be checked one by one. I assume you know BIOS to say "it's all right!" because if you don't that will be your nightmare. It's not so strange because that's even documented in many OS distributions. It may be a hardware issue!

Comment: After some research YES indeed your hardware needs to be compatible with encryption, just to add, check your hardware

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioning a new kernel version, a common problem is an incomplete or broken `initrd` image. Can happen for various reasons, most common being Ubuntu being historically greedy when creating `/boot` partitions which used to be so small, an `initrd` update on several kernel images could easily run out of space.

Try booting from the rescue CD again, and then mount your partitions and devices:

```
mount /dev/ROOT_DEVICE /mnt
mount /dev/BOOT_DEVICE /mnt/boot

mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
```

After that, do a `chroot /mnt` and then try running `update-initramfs -k all -u` while watching its output and `/boot` closely. If successfull, try booting from your normal system again. If `initrd` image has been the reason, you should be able to boot successfully.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I could regenerate the initramfs files, but they still stuck on boot